# How do i fix the Broken pipe error during Ansible Play

Tags: ansible

I am getting this below error while running my Ansible play. It was working perfectly fine till couple of days ago and suddenly started happening for this particular host. I don't know if some configuration change happened on this server but any idea what could be wrong?
The same play works fine for other environment like Prod.

Command

```
ansible-playbook -i my-inventory  my-main.yml --tags=copyRepo-e my_release_version=5.0.0-4 -e target_env=preprod --ask-become-pass
```

I am able to ssh as well

```
server1 | success >> {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

Error

```
<server1> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: user1
<server1> REMOTE_MODULE file state=directory path=/opt/tomcat/releases/Release5.0.0-4/advancederrorsearch/app
<server1> EXEC ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath="/home/user1/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r" -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 server1 /bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p /tmp/ansible-tmp-1586344775.71-121508053477718 && chmod a+rx /tmp/ansible-tmp-1586344775.71-121508053477718 && echo /tmp/ansible-tmp-1586344775.71-121508053477718'
<server1> PUT /tmp/tmp1enuT2 TO /tmp/ansible-tmp-1586344775.71-121508053477718/file
<server1> EXEC ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath="/home/user1/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r" -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 server1 /bin/sh -c 'chmod a+r /tmp/ansible-tmp-1586344775.71-121508053477718/file'
<server1> EXEC ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath="/home/user1/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r" -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 server1 /bin/sh -c 'sudo -k && sudo -H -S -p "[sudo via ansible, key=othmymdswpmqvimfnuimdtsuqtdboprm] password: " -u tomcat /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-othmymdswpmqvimfnuimdtsuqtdboprm; LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /tmp/ansible-tmp-1586344775.71-121508053477718/file'"'"''
<server1> EXEC ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath="/home/user1/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r" -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 server1 /bin/sh -c 'rm -rf /tmp/ansible-tmp-1586344775.71-121508053477718/ >/dev/null 2>&1'
failed: [server1] => (item=advancederrorsearch) => {"failed": true, "item": "advancederrorsearch", "parsed": false}

BECOME-SUCCESS-othmymdswpmqvimfnuimdtsuqtdboprm
couldn't set locale correctly
couldn't set locale correctly
debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2
debug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe
debug2: Received exit status from master 0
Shared connection to server1 closed.
```

Comment: Try this to debug: `ansible -m setup localhost -vvv`

Comment: @ceving I have edited the question with debug.

Comment: Have you checked all the configurations related to remote hosts, on Ansible controller node are matching with actual values on remote hosts? Such as temp directory on remote host, its permissions etc?

Comment: @saurabh14292 Yes I have checked all the configuration. It was working perfectly fine and suddenly it started happening.

Comment: Since you are able to SSH into it, network/authentication is not the issue. Can you post inventory file and playbook? and is it the only error? or can you post entire playbook execution?

Comment: You might be interrested in this [possible workarround](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/67210#issuecomment-585248668) on a bug posted in ansible issues on github (but I'm not 100% sure...)

Comment: @Zeitounator Yeah I saw that while googling but where is this persistent_connection parameter located? I couldn't find it anywhere in my ansible config

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/examples/ansible.cfg

Comment: @Zeitounator Ok i tried that and it didn't work. Still the same issue. :(

Comment: @Zeitounator I was able to resolve it. It was stupid error. Ansible was writing to /tmp folder at my local and it has no space so i cleared space and also changed the local_tmp parameter in my ansible.cfg.