# Validation of parameters and use of roles/tags Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am writing a playbook where I am automating my deployment. In the command line I am passing some parameters which needs to be validated mandatory. I am using roles/tags to run my playbook. Below is my command -

`ansible-playbook -i my-inventory  my-main.yml --tags=copy,deploy -e my_release_version=1.0.0 -e target_env=prod`

In my-main.yml I am first validating the parameters and then executing the roles. Now if i pass tags in the command it is not doing any validation and directly executing the tags which is the way ansible works i guess.

Is there a way to pre execute the steps as mentioned in my-main.yml before executing the tags?

and my-main.yml looks like below -

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
     _allowed_envs:
       - dev
       - preprod
       - prod

  pre_tasks:

     - name: Checking if the Target Environment is ok
       fail:
         msg: >-
           Environment "{{ target_env }}" is not allowed.
           Please choose a target environment from "{{ _allowed_envs | join(', ') }}"
       when: not target_env in _allowed_envs
       run_once: true

  roles:
     - role: copy
       tags:
         - copy
     - role: deploy
       tags:
         - deploy
```

NOTE : My playbook will have roles/tags like copy,deploy and also stoptomcat, starttomcat. So when user only mention tags like stoptomcat and starttomcat I just want one input parameter to be validated target_env because in that case I would not want my_release_version.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can put tags on tasks, pre_tasks, and post_tasks, too.

Comment: There is a [special tag called 'always'](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#special-tags). You can tag your validation task with that and they will always be played, whether or not you specify a tag.

Comment: @Zeitounator You are a Star mate. That worked like a charm. I am feeling stupid now that I couldn't google it out this simple thing. :P

Comment: @Zeitounator Will you be able to help me here? I am stuck on this and tried everything on google but can't figure it out. Let me know if you can help.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61008965/how-do-i-fix-the-broken-pipe-error-during-ansible-play

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the pre_tasks or with your play; *the pre_tasks are skipped because you are passing -**-tags** in the command* line while calling the playbook; hence tags take the highest precedence while invoking the play that is the reason your validation fails each time; If you want to run the pre_tasks, then you dont have to mention ----tags option in cli- and handle the roles-validation with pre-tasks by passing only -e options: something like this

```
---
- name: test_play
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    _allowed_envs:
      - dev
      - preprod
      - prod

  pre_tasks:
    - name: Checking if the Target Environment is ok
      fail:
        msg: >-
         Environment "{{ target_env }}" is not allowed.
         Please choose a target environment from "{{ _allowed_envs | join(', ') }}"
      when: not target_env in _allowed_envs
      run_once: true

  tasks:
    - name: include the dynamic role
      include_role:
        name: "{{ ROLE }}"
      tags: "{{ tag_name }}"
```

and then run it **ansible-playbook  -i my-inventory my-main.yml  -e my_release_version=1.0.0 -e target_env=dev -e ROLE=copy -e tag_name=copy**

[image]

Hope this helps!
Cheers

Comment: Thanks Rizwan for looking into this. This is certainly one of the ways to do it but I was able to achieve it using "always" tag in the pre-task. Thanks again :)

Comment: the above solutions is valid without passing --tags flag- surely  always tag is easy solution and best solution if you pass --tags flag; but if you want --skip tags then above solution is one of the ways which i am using in many scenarios.